# mediawiki urls contain Chinese characters, how to change the urls creating rules for new pages?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, mediawiki

I am setting up a Chinese site with Mediawiki， that means it's written in Chinese. but mediawiki creates a url containing Chinese characters for each new page, I want its urls written in English letters, instead of Chinese words. Can anyone help and tell me how could I change its default url rules?

See the image below, its url has Chinese, but I don't like this.

[image]

Comment: mainly for SEO purposes. Urls containing chinese characters is not SEO friends for Chinese search engines like Baidu， urls made up of English letters are SEO friendly and its index is easy.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an easy way to refer to the page by URL, the [ShortUrl extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ShortUrl) does that. The string it creates for each page is not related to the page title at all (for example, [https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/তারাবাঈ/উপসংহার](https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%88/%E0%A6%89%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%82%E0%A6%B9%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0) gets the link https://bn.wikisource.org/s/11r).

If you want the URL bar to show one string (i.e. in latin-arabic characters) and the page title to be another (i.e. in Chinese) then either the [{{DISPLAYTITLE}} magic word](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#DISPLAYTITLE) or the [Display Title extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Display_Title) can do that (the former changes the title, and the latter gives some extra features such as changing incoming links to the page).

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to use the URL for. If it is for sharing or hyperlinks you can use a URL shortener. Example Google URL shortened (goo.gl/a5gdu7)

Comment: This should be a comment.  If you don't have sufficient rep to leave a comment, then you just have to be an observer for now.

Comment: urls containing chinese characters is not SEO friends for Chinese search engines like Baidu， urls made up of English letters are SEO friendly and its index is easy.